# JBoss does not launch logging in the deployed applications

Tags: java, jboss, log4j

According to [jboss doc](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/Logging+Configuration), the settings from server file `logging.properties` file are

> used when the server boots up until the logging subsystem kicks in.

In the same document, it is said that if we want to set logging rules in the deployed application, we should put one of

logging.properties
jboss-logging.properties
log4j.properties
log4j.xml
jboss-log4j.xml

files into META-INF or WEB-INF/classes. META-INF - for EAR, either of these places - for WAR and JAR. (I have JAR). I had put log4j.properties into resources/META-INF, webapp/META-INF (this one appears later in jar on the highest layer), and in webapp/WEB-INF/classes. All of them I made with different patterns so that I would recognize them when they'll appear.

Also, I added all the other 4 files into all these three places. With different patterns, again. All are present in the jar/META-INF and other appropriate places. But none of them is launched when deployed in the server. Even more, when I edit JBoss's `logging.properties`, the logging changes according to these changes, which means that the server pays no attention at all to any of those logging configurations in the application, even after it "kicks in".

All logging that I see after app deployment, is some server info logging about memory use. Not a line from the app. Even in the case when the browser gets something as error 500, the log is empty.

JBoss AS 6.1

Comment: Do you try variable:
-Dlogging.configuration=[path]/logging.properties
?

Comment: It is set, of course, it belongs to the default run.config.bat. And I had said in the question, that that file IS read and used by the server. But only that one

Comment: Are you referring to JBoss EAP 6.1 here or JBoss AS 6.1?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins JBoss AS 6.1

Comment: That documentation you linked for is for JBoss AS 7+ so it won't work for JBoss AS 6. I'm not sure what is supported for JBoss AS 6.